# Put custom button inside google map v3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have working google map when user click button it will go to user location. but my problem is how to make the button inside the google map? after click google map [] maximize, it show the button. My code is :

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <input id="lat" value="47.6145" />
    <input id="lng" value="-122.3418" />
    <div id="google_map"></div>


    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>

    var map;

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {

      $('#lat').val(position.coords.latitude);
      $('#lng').val(position.coords.longitude);

      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
      //location.reload();

      x.innerHTML = "<p id='babi'>Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "</p><br><p id='setan'>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "</p>";
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var lng = $("#lng").val();
      var lat = $("#lat").val();
      var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      // var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418); //Google map Coordinates

      map_initialize(); // load map
      function map_initialize() {
        //Google map option
        var googleMapOptions = {
          center: mapCenter, // map center
          zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
          panControl: true, //enable pan Control
          zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
          zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
          },
          scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
      }
    });
```

i just want to make  the button try it inside google map when i make google map bigger using [].

my actual work is here : https://jsfiddle.net/designblog4u/kjd6t1L5/ .. i just need to add try it button inside my google map because when i click [] in the map the button not show..

or if anyone know how to integrate my code with below geolocation button like this example : https://jsfiddle.net/ogsvzacz/6/ . it would be apprciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) like [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)

1. wrap your "button" and input elements in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="mapcontrol">
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

  <input id="lat" value="47.6145" />
  <input id="lng" value="-122.3418" />
</div>
```

2. add that to the "custom control" from the example (which is currently centered at the top of the map):

```
function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(document.getElementById('mapcontrol'));
}
```

3. add the control to the map:

```
    // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
    // constructor passing in this DIV.
    var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

    centerControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tw0Lvr5s/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
/**
 * The CenterControl adds a control to the map that recenters the map on
 * the provided coordinates.
 * This constructor takes the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(document.getElementById('mapcontrol'));

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  /* controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  }); */
}



var map;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {

  $('#lat').val(position.coords.latitude);
  $('#lng').val(position.coords.longitude);

  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
  //location.reload();

  x.innerHTML = "<p id='babi'>Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "</p><br><p id='setan'>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "</p>";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var lng = $("#lng").val();
  var lat = $("#lat").val();
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  // var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418); //Google map Coordinates

  map_initialize(); // load map
  function map_initialize() {
    //Google map option
    var googleMapOptions = {
      center: mapCenter, // map center
      zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
      panControl: true, //enable pan Control
      zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
      },
      scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
  }
  // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
  // constructor passing in this DIV.
  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

});
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#google_map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mapcontrol">
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

  <input id="lat" value="47.6145" />
  <input id="lng" value="-122.3418" />
</div>
<div id="google_map"></div>


<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```